# How to generate a "triangular" data frame with as many columns as the row indicates?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this input dataframe

```
 number  
   1  
   2
   3
   4
   6
```

And I want this resulting dataframe

```
 number  C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6
   1      1   nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
   2      1    2   nan  nan  nan  nan
   3      1    2    3   nan  nan  nan
   4      1    2    3    4   nan  nan
   6      1    2    3    4    5    6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please clarify what you mean by 'it doesn't work'?  What happens?  What is the code you used that didn't work.   Please include your code and whatever error messages you get(if any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(df.join(pd.DataFrame(
    df['number']
    .map(lambda x: range(1,x+1)).tolist())
    .rename(lambda x: 'C{}'.format(x+1),axis=1)))
```

Output:

```
   number  C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6
0       1   1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1       2   1  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2       3   1  2.0  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
3       4   1  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN  NaN
4       6   1  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own question, i post my solution here it will surely help someone.

```
max=df1["number"].max()
for i in range(1,max+1):
    df1["column" + str(i)]=np.where(df1["number"] >=(i) , i, np.nan)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd

# Creates the DF
input_df = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], columns=['number'])

# Creates a list from the values in the 'number' column
values_in_column = input_df.number.tolist()

# For each values in our list, create a column in the DF
for val in values_in_column:
    input_df[val] = None

# For each row in the input DF: 
for index, row in input_df.iterrows():

    # Iterate over each column (except the first one)
    for col_val in input_df.columns[1:]:

        # If the value in 'number' at this row is greater of equal to the value of the column header
        if row['number'] >= col_val:

            # Enter the value of the column into the DF
            input_df.at[index, col_val] = col_val
```

This should do what you're looking for. Note, when I make the dataframe, the column headers are integers and not strings like in your question ('C1', 'C2', etc.).

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I think it is not efficient to use for loops to go through the entire dataframe.
The point of using pandas is to apply vectorized solutions.
Even I still appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.